# Is there a way to augment the web-ui build process in Dart to copy my code somewhere else after the build process is finished?

Tags: process, build, copy, dart, dart-webui

I have tried many techniques, but for the life of me, I cannot get this to work.  The technique that gave me the most promise, but still did not work was as follows:

--I noticed that the call to the "build" method (in build.dart) returns a Future, so I assumed that if I were to simply implement the .then () method of that Future, that I could be assured that my code would execute after the entire build process was complete and all files have been properly placed in my web\out directory structure.  In my "then" code, I did a simple recursive copy of everything in web/out to my destination directory.  Now, because of the some of the link changes that take place in abc.html (as a result of the build () method), I had to copy the web/out directory structure into a few different spots in my ultimate detestation, but I don't care about that for now.  The real issue was that when I changed (for example) my abc.css file, and saved it, I figured my build.dart would execute and all file changes would be copied, but alas I was wrong.

2)  During my adventures with #1 above, I figured that I would try to do a "build clean" instead, thinking that this would ensure that I would always have all of the latest files copied to my utlimate destination, but this didn't work either.

My main goal is to get my application quickly copied over to a deployed WAR directory in JBoss so that I can quickly test my REST calls and not rely on the debug server running on port 3030.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to understand the components at work here. (If you didn't already know.)

**build.dart** in your root directory maps to features of the Editor. When it's called and the paramaters passed to it are all in the world of the Editor. I've played with some loggin from this file, just to see when it's called, etc. Just be careful if you write to a file to write to a file outside of your project, or the log updates will kick off another build and it'll never end.

The call to **build**, which is included from package:web_ui/component_build is all about the WebUi compiler. This lives in its own world and simply parties on the arguments passed in from build.dart. It might be worth wile playing with this code yourself outside of build.dart just to see how it works.

https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/blob/master/lib/component_build.dart#L35

If you'd like an example of a tweaked build.dart file, you can look at Widgets. https://github.com/kevmoo/widget.dart/blob/master/build.dart

I'm doing a lot of random cleanup in here. Not sure if it'll be super helpful, but it'll give you ideas.

As far as copying content and getting ready for deploy, I use **Hop**. Here's the hop_runner for widget

https://github.com/kevmoo/widget.dart/blob/master/tool/hop_runner.dart

I break the copy step into its own task. This task just runs a shell script at the moment, although there are some folks working on making a pure Dart version of this.

We'd love help.

Comment: You certainly gave me some things to look at.  I suppose my main question would be do you have any idea how I can detect that their entire build process has completed so that I can perhaps run an ant script or something (to copy my files to their ultimate location)?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific "How do I know when the Web UI build process is done?" question, try something like this:

```dart
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  var args = new List.from(new Options().arguments);
  args.addAll(['--', '--no-rewrite-urls']);

  Future dwc = build(args, ['web/clock_page.html', 'web/HelloWorld.html']);

  dwc
    .then((_) => Process.run('cp', ['packages/browser/dart.js', 'web/out/dart.js']))
    .then((_) => Process.run('cp', ['App.css', 'out']));
}
```

Notice how the `build()` function returns a Future, and you can register functions to be run after the future completes.

Comment: Hopefully there are no Windows users on the team :)

Comment: I'd love a dart:io builtin for copying files. :)

Comment: I guess the shortest is `new File('source').openRead().pipe(new File('target').openWrite())`.